# Like/dislike vote in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am creating a college website which is somewhat like social networking site people can post scraps on each other's wall. I want to include Like/unlike or vote up/vote down on every scrap. I created this table called 
tbl_like ...

LikeId  | ScrapId  | FromId | LikeStatus | Time

Scrap table:
ScrapId   | FromId   |  toId   |msg | sendDate

what do i do next?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewUserScraps" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                GridLines="None" Width="100%" ShowHeader="False" runat="server" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#A5A5A5"
                CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <table align="left" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="2">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href='<%#getUserHREF(Container.DataItem)%>'>
                                            <img align="middle" src='<%#getSRC(Container.DataItem)%>' border="0" width="50px" /></a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        &nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <div align="justify">
                                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Message")%>
                                <br />
                                <br />
                            </div>
                            <span class="SmallBlackText">Posted On: &nbsp;</span>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblSendDate" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"SendDate")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </span>
                            <br />
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnklike" runat="server">Like</asp:LinkButton>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkunlike" runat="server">unlike</asp:LinkButton>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <asp:Label ID="lbllike" runat="server" Text="likes:"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="lbllikecount" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
                <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            </asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            GetUserScraps(int.Parse(Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString()));
        }
    }
    public void GetUserScraps(int Id)
    {
        string getUserScraps = "SELECT u.Id as UserId,u.firstname,u.ImageName,s.FromId,s.ToId,s.Message,s.SendDate,s.ID as ScrapId FROM [User] as u, Scrap as s WHERE u.Id=s.FromId AND s.ToId='" + Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString() + "'";
        string getlikes = "select COUNT(*) from tbl_like inner join Scrap on tbl_like.scrapid=Scrap.Id where tbl_like.likestatus=1 and tbl_like.scrapid=23";
        dt1=
        dt = dbClass.ConnectDataBaseReturnDT(getUserScraps);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GridViewUserScraps.DataSource = dt;
            GridViewUserScraps.DataBind();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `OnItemCommand` event for `GridView`.

In your html:

```
<asp:GridView .... OnItemCommand="CommandLinkClicked">

    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnklike" runat="server" CommandName="like" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ScrapId")%>'>Like</asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkunlike" runat="server"  CommandName="unlike" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ScrapId")%>'>unlike</asp:LinkButton>

</asp:GridView>
```

and in code behind:

```
protected void CommandLinkClicked(object sender, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    var scrapId = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    switch (e.CommandName)
    {
        case "like" : 
                //do stuff
                break;
        case "unlike" : 
                //do stuff
                break;
    }
}
```

`CommandArguemnt` should be id of item that should be updated for like/unlike status.

---

i cleaned up your SQL, now it returns also comment count for every scrap:

```
string getUserScraps = "SELECT u.Id as UserId,u.firstname,u.ImageName,s.FromId,s.ToId,s.Message,s.SendDate,s.ID as ScrapId, ISNULL(COUNT(l.scrapid), 0) as CommentCount FROM Scrap as s INNER JOIN [User] as u on u.Id = s.FromId LEFT  JOIN tbl_like as l on l.scrapid = s.Id and l.likestatus = 1 WHERE s.ToId = '" + Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString() + "' GROUP BY u.Id,u.firstname,u.ImageName,s.FromId,s.ToId,s.Message,s.SendDate,s.ID";
```

And here you have more readable version (it is the same as above!)

```
SELECT u.Id as UserId,u.firstname,u.ImageName,s.FromId,s.ToId,s.Message,s.SendDate,s.ID as ScrapId, ISNULL(COUNT(l.scrapid), 0) as CommentCount
FROM Scrap as s
INNER JOIN [User] as u on u.Id = s.FromId
LEFT  JOIN tbl_like as l on l.scrapid = s.Id and l.likestatus = 1
WHERE s.ToId = 23 --here goes id!
GROUP BY u.Id,u.firstname,u.ImageName,s.FromId,s.ToId,s.Message,s.SendDate,s.ID
```

It count's comment for every scrap, returning 0 if there is no comments. Bind your `GridView` column to CommentCount and it should work just fine

Comment: How can i display the number of likes for every scrap?
select COUNT(*) from tbl_like inner join Scrap on tbl_like.scrapid=Scrap.Id where tbl_like.likestatus=1 and tbl_like.scrapid=???"

Comment: The website i am creating does not have comments like fb, it just has individual scraps like orkut. The problem is that i do not know how to display the number of likes. because in select COUNT(*) from tbl_like inner join Scrap on tbl_like.scrapid=Scrap.Id where tbl_like.likestatus=1 and tbl_like.scrapid=23  (if i use this it will return only the number of likes for scrapid=23) And every row will have same answer. Thank You for your effort btw

Comment: You could iterate for every row returned from first query and run second query for it, but my result is far better (less calls, everything is returned in first sp), so please try to use my proposition - it should work flawlessly :)